# How to transform data rows into new column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

table

```
id      text
1       aaa  
121     bbb
4       ccc 
1       ddd
```

new table

```
id     text2
 1     aaaddd
 121   bbb
 4     ccc
```

I do not think I can use PIVOT since I never know how many and what id and text values would be so I cannot hardcode them in a PIVOT instruction.

Comment: This is called string aggregation, plenty of example of it. It's the same idea as creating a delimited list; just your delimiter is a zero length string (`''`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `group by` with `string_agg`

```
select id,string_agg(text,'') as text2
from table
group by id
```

Comment: Thx for the notice. I made a mistake providing the wrong tag.